# Error spotting : All my hope were duped and I was plunged in deep sorrow

Tags: singular-vs-plural, determiners, countability, predeterminers

> **All my hope** were duped and I was plunged in deep sorrow.

I have two questions regarding the above sentence.

First : Hope is a uncountable noun so is using *were* correct with it or it should be *was* instead of *were* ?

Second : Which is the correct construction between *All my hope* and *My all hope*. I think former one is a correct / better construction, Am I right ?

Comment: *All my hope* is correct but requires singular *was*; *all my hopes were* would be fine, too. It's difficult to conceive how *hope* may be *duped*; perhaps you mean *dashed* or *betrayed* or something of that sort.

Comment: @StoneyB You are  saying that 'All my hopes were' is too fine so does that mean hope can be used as a countable noun too ?

Comment: Yes. You may have non-count *hope*, a general state of anticipating a happy future, or you may have one or more individual *hopes* for specific future eventualities.

Comment: Hopes are usually *dashed*, not *duped* (i.e., *fooled* or *duplicated*).

Comment: "plunged in deep sorrow" might be better as "plunged into deep sorrow" because you are moving in to "deep sorrow"

Answer (score 1):

An idiomatic construction would be to make **hope** plural and to use **dashed** rather than **duped** as to be duped means to be tricked or fooled.

> All my *hopes were dashed* and I was plunged *into* deep sorrow.

*My all hope* is incorrect.